# Why does read-sequence not return upon end of the console stream?

Tags: serial-port, common-lisp

I am opening a serial port with CLISP in Cygwin as an IO stream and found that reading character-by-character is too slow.  For some reason, the stream is being classified as interactive which I believe is causing it to hang with a read smaller than the size of my sequence.

I am interacting with the debug port on a special system.  I intended to spend just a little time to script some interactions, but ended up shaving a yak.

I see a few different ways to resolve this.

1. Read 1 char at a time which allows for read-char-no-hang.  This is too slow.
2. Write a FFI to a serial library.  I don't think I should have to do this.
3. Find some way to determine the remaining length of the stream.  Good solution.
4. Figure out how to make the serial port non-interactive which may cause the read-sequence to return upon end of stream.  This seems like the best solution to me.

   ```
   (with-open-file (serial "/dev/ttyS3" 
                           :direction :io
                           :external-format :unix
                           :if-exists :overwrite)
                      (read-sequence *data* serial)))
   ```

So, per the title, why does read-sequence not return upon the end of the console stream?  Additionally, what is the best way to achieve that behavior?  I'd prefer to stick with the basic CLISP.

Answer (score 1):

First, check your definitions for [READ-SEQUENCE](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/fun_read-sequence.html).

Second, serial data doesn't always have an end-of-file marker (actually, usually doesn't). Maybe your data is getting cooked by the ttyS3 driver, but if this was a raw read, you should assume you have to write your own termination conditions (or implement the ones defined by your device).

Third, serial IO often winds up making you do yak shaving. It's pretty classic network coding, you have to think about packets, frames, speed synchronization and all the usual goodness with protocols. If you're really lucky, your application is simple and you can avoid that.